# Useful links in "Contact" page

Tags: discussion, help-center, contact

I see that the [contact page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/contact) contain some usful links:

- [Facebook Help Center](https://www.facebook.com/help/)
- [Yahoo! Help Central](https://help.yahoo.com/kb/helpcentral)
- [Google Contact](http://www.google.com/contact/)

But it seems that it's kinda weird and out of context. When exactly would a user that want to contact Stackexchange will find these links useful? What is so special about those links as opposed to a link to [Microsoft support](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/contact-support) for example?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> When exactly would a user that want to contact Stackexchange will find these links useful?

When they are looking for Facebook, Yahoo! or Google help though they have ended up landing on a Stack Exchange site first.

Happens more than you would think - folks who have no idea how to navigate the web and are looking for help get to a Stack Exchange site and use the Contact Us page to get this help.

The reason these are the selected ones is simply because this is what the community team has seen - these are the major sites that such users are asking for help with.

Answer (score 5):

Jon Ericson explained the reasoning for these links in his blog post [Building a customer support system: Adding a honeypot](https://jericson.github.io/2015/04/08/customer-support-4.html).

> we get hundreds of support tickets each month that have nothing to do with our sites. It doesn’t help when we actually tried (and failed) to be the official support channel for [Facebook developers](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/facebook-stackoverflow/).
>
> To give you a taste of the tickets we get, here’s one I dug out of the archive:
>
> > Hello, I have been using my password for over 15 years and I am 61 years old and that is my password that I can easily remember [password redacted]. Please put my password on my account

Comment: Is that a pre-collective I'm seeing?